# Can you suggest a regular expression to capture this text?

Tags: c#, regex

Please suggest a regular expression to capture this from the input text below:

```
Match 0:"Modifications made by ... on2011/07/13 06:17:32 from database
keyword: zzzz--> mmmmmm
total_effort: --> 0.00
tmp__effort: --> 0
resolver"

Match 1:"Modifications made by ... on2011/07/13 06:19:32 from database
resolver"
```

Input text:

```
Modifications made by... on 2011/06/21 14:09:14 from database
problem_description: (text value has changed)


Modifications made by ... on2011/07/13 06:17:32 from database
keyword: zzzz--> mmmmmm
total_effort: --> 0.00
tmp__effort: --> 0
resolver: y --> x
total_t_effort: --> 0.00

Modifications made by ... on2011/07/13 06:19:32 from database
resolver: x --> z
total_t_effort: --> 0.00
```

I've tried using this `modifications\smade\sby(.|\n)+?resolver` but it gives me incorrect output:

```
Match 0:"Modifications made by... on 2011/06/21 14:09:14 from database
problem_description: (text value has changed)


Modifications made by ... on2011/07/13 06:17:32 from database
keyword: zzzz--> mmmmmm
total_effort: --> 0.00
tmp__effort: --> 0
resolver"
Match 1:"Modifications made by ... on2011/07/13 06:19:32 from database
resolver"
```

Options used: `IgnoreCase + MultiLine`

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex for this it gets a bit more complicated.

Try

```
^modifications\smade\sby(.(?!modifications))+?resolver
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2upmp)

I removed the `\n` and used the **[Singleline option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)** instead.

The idea is, match every character till the next "resolver", but only when this character is not followed by "modifications". Therefore I used the negative lookahead `.(?!modifications)`.

Comment: Wow! I was trying something like that. Thank you so much! Since there is no `dotall` option in C# (as far as I know), i will use this `modifications\smade\sby((.|\n)(?!modifications))+?resolver`. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, this option is called Singleline in .NET [see on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)